# how to select and append in MSSQL to C# code

Tags: c#, sql-server

i want to select the last 2 queries of my table and append only a certain column and add a certain column, images is displayed below to understand my question better.

this is my select in my database. 2 rows the difference is the quantity, po num and date purchased.
[image: image1]

this is my expected output, as you can see, my quantity is added but my PU_Num and Date_Purchased was appended. 
[image: image2]

is my idea valid? is it possible? thanks!

Comment: Without code, your question is arguably a _set of requirements_. [ask]

Comment: Yes. You want to use `CONCAT()` function

Comment: @scsimon `CONCAT()` and `SUM()` function? how will i start my code? i am new to mssql

Comment: That's right. Sorry I'm on my mobile so hard to answer. I'm positive someone will help within 15 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.Company, t.Model, t.Quantity, t.Type, t.Status, 
       PO_Num = stuff(p.po_num, 1, 1, ''),
       Date_Purchased = stuff(d.date_purchased, 1, 1, ''),
       v.last_2_qty
from   
(
     -- get the required sum of quantity
     select t.Company, t.Model, Quantity = SUM(t.Quantity), t.Type, t.Status
     from   yourtable t
     group by t.Company, t.Model, t.Type, t.Status
) t
-- get the last 2 PO num by date_purchased
-- using for xml path to concatenate the PO Num into CSV
cross apply 
(
    select TOP 2 ',' + x.PO_Num
    from   yourtable x
    where  x.Company = t.Company
    and    x.Model   = t.Model
    order by x.Date_Purchased desc
    for xml path('')
) p (po_num)
-- get the last 2 date_purchased
cross apply  
(
    select TOP 2 ',' + convert(varchar(10), x.Date_Purchased, 121)
    from   yourtable x
    where  x.Company = t.Company
    and    x.Model   = t.Model
    order by x.Date_Purchased desc
    for xml path('')
) d (date_purchased)
-- sum of the last 2 value
cross apply  
(
    select last_2_qty = sum(Quantity)
    from
    (
      -- get the last 2 quantity
      select TOP 2 x.Quantity
      from   yourtable x
      where  x.Company = t.Company
      and    x.Model   = t.Model
      order by x.Date_Purchased desc
    ) v
) v
```

Comment: hi @Squirrel , the po_num and date_purchased, says Ambiguous column, how come?

Comment: added column alias. try

Comment: hi @Squirrel, it says `Column 'p.po_num' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
`

Comment: hi @Squirrel, the error now is `Column 't.Company' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: hi @Squirrel, it works! but it shows all datas, i only need the latest 2 datas.

Comment: added `TOP 2` and `ORDER BY` condition to the `date purchased` sub-query

Comment: the date purchased is corrent, but the PO_NUM records is not, it does not display 10002 or 100006

Comment: so it is also based on last 2 by dates ? added similar condition to the po_num query.

Comment: yup! wow! thanks man! big thanks! can i ask what the `cross apply` mean? how does it differ from `inner join`?

Comment: it is easier to refer to here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Squirrel -- I just have to say that you are so flipping awesome!

Comment: hey @Squirrel just wondering, how can i also get the sum of the last 2 values? not all quantities? thanks!

Comment: yes. you can use another `CROSS APPLY` to sum the value

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_

Comment: the description was comments in between code. I have added further explaination

Comment: hi @Squirrel how can i input that into the cross apply? just getting the sum of the last 2 values. not all values